# Dynamic Date To Track The Maturity Date of Automatic Rollover Deposit

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

Suppose that I open an automatic rollover time deposit (ARO TD) account in a bank on January 17, 2017 (the value date). The funds in this account must be held for 3 months (the tenor). Since it's an ARO TD, the maturity date will be automatically renewed with no action required by me if I choose to do nothing. Today's date is July 18, 2017. So, my account will mature on October 17, 2017. If I open it on January 19, 2017, it will mature on July 19, 2017, and so on.

[image]

How do I track the maturity date of my account in Excel with only using inputs: deposit period and value date? Meaning, the maturity date will continually update to the next period each time it matures. I'm able to find the Excel formula for this:

```
=IF(EDATE(B2,A2*CEILING(DATEDIF(B2,TODAY(),"M")/A2,1))<TODAY(),EDATE(B2,A2*(1+CEILING(DATEDIF(B2,TODAY(),"M")/A2,1))),EDATE(B2,A2*CEILING(DATEDIF(B2,TODAY(),"M")/A2,1)))
```

The above formula works perfectly but it's too long. Could anyone here come up with a nicer and shorter formula than this?

Comment: So you want the **earliest future date** that is an exact multiple of *tenor* months after *value date*, right?

Comment: @AakashM Yup...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DATEDIF` function to do this. For reasons I don't understand, Excel doesn't suggest it when you're typing, but [it exists and is documented](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/DATEDIF-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c).

`DATEDIF` is useful because you're interested in the number of months between dates. The earlier date of interest is the value date; the later date is today (actually yesterday, because as in your first example you want the date to tick on *on* the expiry date).

Once you have this number of months, you can get the exact number of tenors that is, add one, and then add that many months to the value date.

A formula is actually easier than the above text!

Your `C2` cell should be:

```
=EDATE(B2, A2 * (FLOOR( DATEDIF(B2, TODAY()-1, "m") / A2, 1) + 1))
```

Working outwards from the middle, the `DATEDIF` gets the number of months from the value date to yesterday, we divide it by the tenor and floor to get the number of tenor periods that have passed, we add one to get the target number of tenor periods, we multiple by the tenor to get the number of *months* to add, then finally `EDATE` does the month-adding.

The result will be a date serial (eg `43025`) so will need appropriate cell formatting.

Comment: The error occurs using your suggested formula. Do you mean: `=EDATE(B2,A2*(FLOOR(DATEDIF(B2, TODAY()-1, "M")/A2,1)+1))`? If so, it works perfectly

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀 yup, had to manually copy from another machine and got the parentheses wrong. Fixed now.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Upvoted & accepted. :)